# How i can include matrix transpose code here c++

Tags: c++, matrix, transpose

i have this code where it's just simple matrix, i type in matrix in .txt file and get it printed it rezults.txt file, but now, i'm trying to transpose that matrix and can't figure out how i can include transpose function into my code, this is all i got right now

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char* matrixa = "data.txt";
const char* rez = "rez.txt";

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    int* A;

    ifstream fd(matrixa);
    if (fd.fail()) {
        cerr << "Nepavyko atidaryti " << matrixa << " failo skaitymui." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    fd >> n >> m;
    A = new int[n * m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            fd >> *(A + i * m + j);
    fd.close();
    ofstream fr(rez);
    fr << "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        fr << setw(3) << i << "  ";
    fr << endl;
    fr << "----------";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fr << "---------";
    fr << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fr << i << " | ";
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            fr << setw(3) << *(A + i * m + j) << "   ";
        fr << endl;
    }
    fr.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and to transpose matrix i've been trying to use something like this

```cpp
void transpose(int A[][N], int B[][N])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            B[i][j] = A[j][i];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Place your matrix in a 2D array - that's what the transpose function takses.

Comment: @WaisKamal I'm using matrix in .txt file, i should add in code ```int 2D[3][3];``` ?